# Getting php echo to float around image

Tags: php, html, css, echo

I'm by no means an expert, but I manage to get by, more or less.

I have created a "box" on my website with a specific size.

Lets just call it

```
<div class="newsbox" style="size, width etc.">
```

Inside that class, I have placed an image like this (the $this-getThemePath is CMS-specific):

```
<div class="image" style="position:fixed; top:15%; left:20%; padding-top: 3px; padding-left:3px; float:left;">
<img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath()?>/images/postit_today.png"></div>
```

After that, I have a loop writing out content from my database like this:

```
<div class="newsstyling" style="font-size: 16px;"><?php echo nl2br($news .= "\n");?></div>
```

Lastly, I close the -tag for my "newsbox"

In my, admittedly newbie, mind, any text being written out via the loop, should float around the image above. It doesn't. It ignores the image and writes the text underneath it.

Any tips, hints, links or guides would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/ht/wrap_text_image.htm

Comment: @1ntello - both yes and no. I know how float works, but I wasn't aware that "position:fixed" ruined it. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

that's because you're using `position:fixed` , positioned elements are outside the normal flow of a web page, try this instead:

```
<img style="float:left" /><div>my text, foo, bar, etc.....</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath()?>/images/postit_today.png">
```

to

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath()?>/images/postit_today.png" style="float:right" hspace=10 vspace=10>
```

Comment: Couldn't get that to work. David fixed it for me :-)